# Why does FreeBSD pkg install process exit silently?

Tags: freebsd

New to FreeBSD and want to install vim using pkg install vim. The first step was all right and after confirming the process started, but after the first dependency was installed, the process just exited silently.

```
Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
[1/110] Fetching libidn-1.33_1.txz: 100%  201 KiB 102.7kB/s    00:02
root@freebsd-dev:~ #
```

I have tried several times and the installing process always exited early. Am I missing something when using pkg install command? Any help will be appreciated. (I run FreeBSD 10.3 in the VirtualBox and running pkg -v returns 1.10.1)

Comment: What is the exit code? Try `echo $?` after the `pkg`.

Comment: @uzsolt It returns "3" as the exit code.